Java Netbeans + SQL Server - MVC - Date from Java is not saving in the database
I'm using the model MVC to create an inventory management system. I apologies that my code is some part in Spanish but I think it'd be easy to understand.
Everything was ok with my system. The connection to the database is ok but when I'm inputing data from my JDateChooser, at first it couldn't be saved in my database because of the format, I believe I fixed it but after that the parameter is not receiving any data and it's giving an error that it receiving nulls.
This is the code from my controller:
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == vistaProductos.btnRegistrarEntradas) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    DAOI.registrarInsumos(new InsumosSalidas(
        vistaProductos.txtNombreEntradas.getText(),
        Double.parseDouble(vistaProductos.txtPrecioEntradas.getText()),
        vistaProductos.cbxMonedaSalidas.getSelectedItem().toString(),
        vistaProductos.cbxAlmacenajeEntradas.getSelectedItem().toString(),
        vistaProductos.txtDescripcionEntradas.getText(),
        Integer.parseInt(vistaProductos.txtProveedorEntradas.getText()),
        sdf.format(vistaProductos.dateFechaEntradas.getDate()),
        Double.parseDouble(vistaProductos.txtCantidadEntradas.getText())
    ));

    mostrarEntradas();
}

This is the code from my DAO:
package Modelo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import Conexion.ConexionBD;

public class DAOInsumosSalidas {
    
    Connection cn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    
    public void registrarInsumos(InsumosSalidas i) {
        try {
            cn = ConexionBD.getConexionBD();
            String sql = "insert into Insumos (nombre, precio, moneda, almacenaje, descripcion, idProveedor, fecha, stock) "
                    + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, i.getNombre());
            ps.setDouble(2, i.getPrecio());
            ps.setString(3, i.getMoneda());
            ps.setString(4,i.getAlmacenaje());
            ps.setString(5, i.getDescripcion());
            ps.setInt(6, i.getIdProveedor());
            ps.setString(7, i.getFecha());
            ps.setDouble(8, i.getStock());
            
            ps.execute();
            ps.close();
            cn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    
    public DefaultTableModel getInsumo() {
        String [] cabecera = {"Codigo","Nombre","Cantidad","Precio","Proveedor","Stock","Fecha"};
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null,cabecera);        
        int cod;
        String nom;
        double cant;
        double pre;
        String pro;
        double stock;
        String fecha;
        try {
            cn = ConexionBD.getConexionBD();
            ps = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT i.idInsumo as codigo, i.nombre, hc.cantidadCambio, i.precio, p.nombre as proveedor, i.stock, hc.FechaCambio FROM Insumos AS i INNER JOIN HistorialCambios AS hc ON i.idInsumo = hc.idInsumo INNER JOIN Proveedor AS p ON p.idProveedor = i.idProveedor");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                cod = rs.getInt(1);
                nom = rs.getString(2);
                cant = rs.getDouble(3);
                pre = rs.getDouble(4);
                pro = rs.getString(5);
                stock = rs.getDouble(6);
                fecha = rs.getString(7);
                Object [] fila = {cod,nom,cant,pre,pro,stock,fecha};
                modelo.addRow(fila);
            }
            ps.close();
            cn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return modelo;
    }
}

And this is the code from the model:
package Modelo;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class InsumosSalidas {
    private String nombre;
    private double precio;
    private String moneda;
    private String almacenaje;
    private String descripcion;
    private int idProveedor;
    private String fecha;
    private double stock;
    
    // Constructor

    public InsumosSalidas(String nombre, double precio, String moneda, String almacenaje, String descripcion, int idProveedor, String fecha, double stock) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.moneda = moneda;
        this.almacenaje = almacenaje;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.idProveedor = idProveedor;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.stock = stock;
    }
    
    public InsumosSalidas() {}

    // Getter y Setter
    
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public String getMoneda() {
        return moneda;
    }

    public void setMoneda(String moneda) {
        this.moneda = moneda;
    }

    public String getAlmacenaje() {
        return almacenaje;
    }

    public void setAlmacenaje(String almacenaje) {
        this.almacenaje = almacenaje;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public int getIdProveedor() {
        return idProveedor;
    }

    public void setIdProveedor(int idProveedor) {
        this.idProveedor = idProveedor;
    }

    public String getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(String fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public double getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(double stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }
    

}

In my data base it saves all the data but the date.
idInsumo    nombre  precio  moneda  almacenaje  descripcion idProveedor fecha   stock
11113   asd 120 S/. Aromaticos  assdasd 11112   NULL    20
11114   asd 120 S/. Aromaticos  assdasd 11112   NULL    20
11115   asd 20  S/. Aromaticos  asd 11112   NULL    20
And this is the error I get.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:792)
    at Controlador.ControladorProductos.actionPerformed(ControladorProductos.java:49)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2314)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:407)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6620)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6385)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4995)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:98)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Does anyone have any suggestions
I tried fixing the format for my class attribute or in the controller trying to change the format.

Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for all of your date and time work. The class you need for a date is LocalDate. And don’t transfer dates as strings to your database. Transfer LocalDate objects and save yourself the trouble of formatting them. Find a date picker component that supports LocalDate, there are some. The classes you were trying to use, Date and in particuler SimpleDateFormat, had notorious, severe design problems and have fortunately been outdated for 10 years. Stay away from them.

With your PreparedStatement just use ps.setObject(7, yourLocalDate);. Provided that your JDBC connector is JDBC 4.2 compliant (which they are today), it will solve your issue, and you will need nothing more. You may read more here: Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2.
